# Can't move mails anymore in Outlook 2016

Tags: windows-10, email, microsoft-outlook-2016, drag-and-drop

I have `Microsoft Office Home and Business 2016` Version 1706 (Build 8229.2086) and since lately I can't drag and drop an email to a folder.

I searched in Google and tried a few tips, but none of them helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I noticed that drag-and-drop didn't worked on my Windows 10 machine. Neither moving shortcuts nor moving files in explorer did work. Now I restarted my machine and everything is now as it should be. Don't know if there was an update or if a process blocked this ...

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered this or a similar problem on my own computer (a Mac); in addition to the symptom you listed, I also wasn't able to mark messages as read or as junk. The cause was a corrupted message database when I completely filled my hard disk, but Outlook 2016 doesn't seem to have the ability to force a repair of its database. Supposedly, you can maybe force a repair of the database by creating a new user profile, but that didn't work for me. I ended up restoring my Outlook profile directory from a backup and everything worked afterwards.

Comment: I tried `SCANPST.EXE` to repair the pst file without success (88 errors found). My disk space is big enough, but of course there could be an error in it. The interesing question is, that I can move the mail via right click or ribbon, but not with drag and drop ...

Answer (score 0):

This problem appears when there's at least one email with too large subject title, among the emails we are trying to drag.

The solution for me was to find that email (maybe more than one) with too large subject title (too many words), and delete it. Then it is possible to drag or to move the entire amount of emails to another file.

Source: MY OWN EXPERIENCE